# ¿Cómo generar un numero aleatorio con SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito generara un numero aleatorio entre 1 y 99 pero sin decimales. Intente un `select` como el siguiente:

```
SELECT RAMD () 1 AND 99
```

Pero el mismo me da error busque en Google y no entendí.

Comment: la función no es RAMD() es RAND(), luego esta función devuelve un número float entre 0 y 1, en caso de que quieras un numero entre 1 y 99 tendrías que hacer "select floor(rand()*98) as numero", por ultimo en sqlserver la función RAND() no funciona muy bien, ya que devuelve el mismo valor si se ejecuta varias veces en la misma transacción, por tanto si quieres números diferentes deberás buscar otra función, espero que te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server dispone desde la versión 2005 de la función [`RAND()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql) la cual retorna un número de coma flotante pseudo aleatorio. La forma de generar números enteros en un determinado rango es usando la siguiente formula:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(end-start)+start);
```

En tu ejemplo sería algo así:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(99-1)+1);
```

**Importante:**

[`RAND()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql) recibe un parámetro `seed` que es la semilla del generador aleatorio, hay que tener en cuenta que si indicamos una determinada semilla en cualquier momento, la generación de números será siempre la misma. Esto `SELECT RAND(100), RAND(), RAND()` siempre nos retornará los mismos tres números.

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta de [`RAND()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql) es si se usa dentro de un `SELECT`. Si hacemos algo así: `SELECT id, RAND() FROM Tabla` obtendremos siempre el mismo número, esto es por que implícitamente se usa siempre la misma semilla, en estos casos la solución es usar un valor distinto por fila como "semilla", podría ser `ROW_NUMBER()` pero puede ser demasiado obvia , la otra alternativa es usar [`NEWID()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql) de la siguiente forma: `SELECT id, RAND(CAST( NEWID() AS varbinary)) FROM Tabla`

Answer (score 4):

Te dejo el ejemplo, espero te sirva

```
SELECT ROUND(((99 - 1) * RAND() + 1), 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Una primera opción es utilizando la funcion rand()
Lo utilizo de la siguiente manera:

```
declare @NumeroDesde int = 1000 ;
declare @NumeroHasta int = 9999 ;
SELECT ROUND(((@NumeroHasta - @NumeroDesde) * RAND() + @NumeroDesde), 0)
```

Para generar por ejemplo código de 4 dígitos.

Una segunda opción utilizando las funciones checksum y newid:

```
select  abs(checksum(newid()))
```

El newid() obtiene un valor alfanumérico largo, el checksum minimiza esto, pero hay veces que obtiene valores en negativos, por lo que al utilizar abs() se obtiene el valor absoluto.